# What is a good approach for connecting from by Kubuntu 10 system to Windows

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop, kubuntu

What will give me the best remote connection look and feel, with a step by step guide.

I am trying to connect to my Kubuntu system from Windows.  I don't need to go the other way.  I believe I used VNC viewer in the past but the performance wasn't very good, it seemed that I was getting 1 frame a second.

Also, should I be concerned about secured.  The connection is between a windows xp machine and kubuntu 10 on a wired local network.

Comment: Which direction do you want to connect to? You say "from Kubuntu to Windows" in the title, but "to Kubuntu from Windows" in the post itself.

Answer (score 2):

[FreeNX](http://freenx.berlios.de/) is an excellent remote desktop solution for Linux that is faster than VNC and features built-in SSH tunneling to secure your connection.

Packages for Ubuntu are available from a PPA on Launchpad.  There are [complete installation instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX) in the Ubuntu Community Documentation.  There is also a closed-source [client application for Windows](http://www.nomachine.com/download-package.php?Prod_Id=2581).

Answer (score 0):

The best choice for remote desktop connections to Windows is... **Remote Desktop**. Try `rdesktop`, `krdesktop`, and `remmina` as Linux clients.

Comment: And all can be used through a ssh tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

Kubuntu 10.10 comes with pre-installed desktop sharing app, KRBF. It generates invitation for the client PC. Never used it, though, I usually go the other way . I use Kubuntu the other way round, to command the Windows machine with KRDC and I am very happy with it.